# Referring to the same dynamic range across multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looping to create a generic range which I want to apply to 8 worksheets (which are identical apart from values.)

```
For j = 2 To blockNo
row1 = 3 + (j - 1) * (pronum + 18)
row2 = row1 + pronum - 1
Set rng2 = Union(rng2, Range("Q" & row1 & ":BA" & row2))
Next j

For k = 1 To 8
Sheets(k).Activate
rng2.Copy........
```

It's not working because rng2 is worksheet specific, so it's copying the range values from sheet 1.

I think the following may be a solution, but it's not elegant and would be slow.

```
For k = 1 To 8
    Sheets(k).Activate
    For j = 2 To blockNo
    row1 = 3 + (j - 1) * (pronum + 18)
    row2 = row1 + pronum - 1
    Set rng2 = Union(rng2, Range("Q" & row1 & ":BA" & row2))
    Next j
    rng2.Copy........
```

I've tried sheets(k).range(rng2.address), but this appears to be limited to certain number of characters so my range doesn't capture the whole of rng2.

Is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the address is too long to pass to `.Range()` directly, the best I can think of is to manually recreate the range using `Union`:

```
For j = 2 To blockNo
    row1 = 3 + (j - 1) * (pronum + 18)
    row2 = row1 + pronum - 1
    Set rng2 = Union(rng2, Range("Q" & row1 & ":BA" & row2))
Next

Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim target As Range
For k = 1 To 8
    Set sheet = Sheets(k)
    Set target = sheet.Range(rng2.Cells(1, 1).Address)
    Dim cell as Range
    For Each cell In rng2.Cells
        Set target = Union(sheet.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column), target)
    Next cell
    sheet.Activate
    rng2.Copy........
Next
```